# Difference between var and this in Javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, syntax

```
var tools = {};

tools.triangle = function() {
    var originX = 0;
    var originY = 0;
}
```

```
var tools = {};

tools.triangle = function() {
    this.originX = 0;
    this.originY = 0;
}
```

Are there any differences between these two code blocks? Sorry if this has been asked before.

Comment: `var` variable is private. `this` variable is public.

Comment: @elclanrs—that comment is unhelpful because it is misleading. Variables can be declared as globals, `this` is related to execution context, it is not a variable in the usual sense, though it can be considered a local variable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`var` creates a local variable within `tools.triangle`. The variables `originX` and `originY` cannot be interacted with outside of `tools.triangle`. `this` is a pointer to the current object you are dealing with. The second example can be used to give properties to an object by doing `new tools.triangle();`. If you do not use `new` and just use `tools.triangle();`, `this` will point the global object which is the `window` object. You can change the object to which `this` points by using the function methods [`call();`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFUQFjAA&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call&ei=F-TwT77tLuS26wHZr62UBg&usg=AFQjCNFv3KJ_elOprlTCrEkrXUnsT4CMpQ) and [`apply();`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFMQFjAA&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply&ei=LuTwT82OL4TH6wGW9diQBg&usg=AFQjCNFgkF2xdtJvcGkuRqEINJyJimDgQw) like this:

```
var myObj = {};

tools.triangle.call( myObj );

// "this" in tools.triangle now points to myObj
// myObj now has the properties originX and originY
```

It is important to know that `this` can reference any object, as well as be undefined or `null` in ES5 strict mode.

You can find more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: `this` needs more explanation than provided, it is set by the call and can reference **any** object, as well as be undefined or `null` in ES5 strict mode.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Thank you for your answer. I really was looking for this. I also wasn't aware of the fact that the `call`(and `apply`) method could change the scope.

Comment: The answer needs correction around the scenario when `new` is not used. Since `triangle` is an instance function of `tools` object, `this` points to `tools` object and calling `tools.triangle()` will actually create the properties `originX` and `originY` on the tools object.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, X and Y both exist as local variables to the closure saved in the variable `triangle`.

In the second example, X and Y exist as variables to the object `tools.triangle` because of the use of `this`.