# Javascript: this.varName = "" vs var varName = ""

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm new to JS so noob question:

I see functions which define vars inside them:

```
 function functionName(){
     this.something = "";
 };
```

If I understand correctly, `something` is a local variable? Why is it being defined as `this.something = ''` as opposed to `var something = ''`?
Is there any difference, and if so what is it?

Comment: this relates to the scope of the variable, http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/

Comment: You may want to check out this question and its accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope?rq=1 tl;dr: use of `var` makes something a variable scoped to that context; omitting the `var` implicitly marks the variable as global; using `this` makes it a property of the execution context (the `this` object)

Comment: Check if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285975/difference-between-var-and-this-in-javascript-functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sets the attribute `something` of `this`. What `this` refers to depends on how `functionName` is invoked, but typically it's an object created with `new`:

```
var foo = new functionName();
console.log(foo.something);
```

If you'd use `var something` inside the function, the variable would be inaccessible from outside, so you couldn't do `foo.something` in the above example.

Answer (score 1):

```
var someThing
```

is a local variable - meaning it exists within the scope of the current block

```
this.someThing
```

is an instance variable - meaning it belongs to the object and is visible in all methods of that object.