# What is the difference between `this` and `var` in a function.

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript code from a project at school. (This code was provided for me.)   Can someone explain the difference between `var SetDataRequest` and  `this.SetDataRequest`  I understand what is happening in the functions, just not why the functions are created in this fashion.   Is it similar to overloading?

```
Tele.Forms.Controller = new function () {
  var _requestData; 
  this.SetRequestData = function (requestData) {
        _requestData = requestData;
  };

  var SetRequestData = function () {
    var fields = $('.FormsMainTable');
    var reqData = ['REQUEST_RECORD_ID', 'DATE_SUBMITTED', 'REQUESTER_ID'];
    ....
    ....
  };

  ....
  ....
};
```

Comment: here you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285975/difference-between-var-and-this-in-javascript-functions

Comment: Please try to make your question title a summary of your question.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tvCST/

Comment: C'mon folks.  there's certainly no reason to hammer me with the downvotes. I tried searching for my answer before asking, I just didn't get these results.  Thank you to the people that did provide helpful feedback.

Answer (score 1):

`this.setRequestData` is available at `Tele.Forms.Controller.setRequestData`, while `var SetRequestData` is only available to the internals of the function.  Think of `this.setRequestData` as the API of the `Tele.Forms.Controller` object, and `SetRequestData` as one of the internal methods that allows the API to work (I'm making an assumption that `...` makes some connections between `this.setRequestData` and `SetRequestData`).

Answer (score 1):

`object = new function () {..}` is to to create a function object and also define the constructor for the function object.

Inside the function object constructor you can use the expression `this.new_var = function () {..}` to add to or modify a public member function of the object, or if you declare the function object separately, of any object which uses the same function constructor:
e.g

```
//define new function object
function Car() {
    this.paint = function (...) {..};
}
//construct new object
var myCar = new Car();
//then you can use myCar.paint(...)
```

The expression `var something = ...` in the the function object constructor is used to make private member variables or functions.
The expression `var something = function() {...}` inside the function object (*notice without the key word `new`) simply creates a private member function for the object.

*Read more useful informations here: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html