# IIFE: var vs this - is there any difference?

Tags: javascript, this, var, iife

Is there any difference between `this` and `var` in immediately invoced function expressions(IIFE)?

```
(function(){
    var foo = 0;
    this.bar = 0;
})();
```

Comment: `this` sets global variable, `var` local. Check `console.log(this === window)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285975/difference-between-var-and-this-in-javascript-functions

Answer (score 2):

If your code is executed in the global context, then two options:

1. You're in `use strict` mode, and in which case `this` points to nothing (null or undefined) and then you'll see an exception.
2. You're not in `use strict` mode and then `this` points to the window, in which case you'll set `bar` as a global variable.

`var` keeps the variable local (same scope it is run in) and will not be exposed to outside calls of the IIFE.

Answer (score 1):

`var` is a local-scoped variable. That is, it won't be available outside the IIFE.

In the other hand, `this.bar` adds a property to current object. In your case it's `window`.

I would recommend the following solution if you want to export variables, functions or any member to other scope:

```
   var MyModule = (function(exports){
        var foo = 0;
        exports.bar = 0;

        return exports;
    })(MyModule || {});
```

Above code is a simple implementation of *module pattern*.

In the other hand, if you want to define *what's `this` inside the IIFE*, you can invoke it using `call`:

```
   // You don't need "exports" anymore
   // since "this" works the same way
   var MyModule = (function(){
        var foo = 0;
        this.bar = 0;

        return this;
    }).call(MyModule || {});
```

At the end of the day, the value of `this` depends on how a function is called. If you don't provide the meaning of `this` with [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FFunction%2Fcall), [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), it will depend on how the function is called. For example, if a function is part of an object, then `this` will be the object who owns the function:

```
var obj = {
    doStuff: function() {
         // "this" is "obj" by default
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is.

- `foo` is a variable scoped within the IIFE
- `bar` will be evaluated against whatever `this` is bound to in the execution context.