# Javascript class variables - this. or var

Tags: javascript

Should 'this.' or 'var' be used to create variables in a Javascript class or does it not matter which is used.  Obviously those defined with this. will be accessible from outside the object whereas those defined with var will not but are there any other differences?

```html
function myClass() {
 this.count = 0;
 this.oTimer = null;
    this.getCount = function() { return(this.count); }
}
oMyObj = new myClass();
oMyObj.getCount();  // returns 0
```

as opposed to

```html
function myClass2() {
 var count = 0;
 var oTimer = null;
    this.getCount = function() { return(count); }
}
oMyObj = new myClass2();
oMyObj.getCount();  // returns 0
```

Comment: `var` makes count hidden. For `this.count`, you can access count by doing `oMyObj.count`  Read about javascript scope and closures.

Comment: Lexical scoping my friend :)

Comment: It entirely depends on the visibility you want. Use of "this" means "it is a visible member of this class". It also communicates that intent to other developers. use of "var" means "not to be used outside" (and again, communicates that intent). However, do note that in JavaScript, in the end it is generally possible to get at any piece of data regardless of how the developer tried to hide it. Module patterns and such come a long way to catch compile-time violations and such, but good 'ol bracket notation trumps pretty much anything.

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285975/difference-between-var-and-this-in-javascript-functions

Comment: Thanks Suchit, that link provides a good explanation, hadn't seen that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to explain a little bit more in detail than Dominique in the comments:

if you use the `var` keyword, the variable is only valid in the scope they are run. This means that after the constructor is run (the function body), the variables get lost (as they were only valid inside the constructor).

If you want to access the variables outside of the constructor (e.g. member-methods), you have to bind the variables to the class itself via the `this` keyword. Now their scope is the class itself, not just the constructor.

---

Edit:

Explaining further: while you can use the variables declared with `var` inside of methods that you also declared inside the constructor because they are defined in the same scope (see example of Question), it is not possible to access them through any other added methods that you add via `Function.prototype`.

To show this, I have created a little [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/oo2gamzn/3/)

So it is generally better practice to define all variables of a class (that you don't only intent to use as temporary variables inside the constructor) with the `this` keyword.

Comment: Michael, just tested that theory but it appears that variables declared with var are in-fact visible to member methods, just like those declared with this.  Will edit examples in original post to demonstrate.

Comment: @NickC yea but thats only because you defined the method in the same scope (constructor). Look at this fiddle where I tried the other method of adding member-methods (via prototype): https://jsfiddle.net/oo2gamzn/1/ . While it might work with vars when you define the methods inside of the function-body, its generally just better practice to use `this` for variables that are used outside of the constructor

Comment: Michael, thanks for that jsfiddle that explains the difference completely, now I understand.  I had a feeling there was a difference but couldn't understand what it was.  Cheers,

If you would like to repeat that as an answer I can mark that as the accepted solution.

Comment: @NickC sure. I just added that to my original answer above